# JSON Schema validation in PostgreSQL?

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonschema, postgresql-json

I can't find any information about JSON schema validation in PostgreSQL, is there any way to implement JSON Schema validation on PostgreSQL JSON data type?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is a [PostgreSQL extension](https://github.com/gavinwahl/postgres-json-schema) that implements JSON Schema validation in PL/PgSQL.

It is used like this (taken from the project README file):

```sql
CREATE TABLE example (id serial PRIMARY KEY, data jsonb);
ALTER TABLE example ADD CONSTRAINT data_is_valid CHECK (validate_json_schema('{"type": "object"}', data));

INSERT INTO example (data) VALUES ('{}');
-- INSERT 0 1

INSERT INTO example (data) VALUES ('1');
-- ERROR:  new row for relation "example" violates check constraint "data_is_valid"
-- DETAIL:  Failing row contains (2, 1).
```

Comment: Did you know if there are any performance - load tests for this validation ?

Comment: I do not know. The code is quite short (259 lines) of a pretty straight-forward PL/PgSQL, which is interpreted. You should measure it with your own schema.

Answer (score 35):

There is another [PostgreSQL extension](https://github.com/furstenheim/is_jsonb_valid) that implements json validation. The usage is almost the same as "Postgres-JSON-schema"

```
CREATE TABLE example (id serial PRIMARY KEY, data jsonb);
-- do is_jsonb_valid instead of validate_json_schema
ALTER TABLE example ADD CONSTRAINT data_is_valid CHECK (is_jsonb_valid('{"type": "object"}', data));

INSERT INTO example (data) VALUES ('{}');
-- INSERT 0 1

INSERT INTO example (data) VALUES ('1');
-- ERROR:  new row for relation "example" violates check constraint "data_is_valid"
-- DETAIL:  Failing row contains (2, 1).
```

I've done some benchmarking validating tweets and it is 20x faster than "Postgres-JSON-schema", mostly because it is written in C instead of SQL.

Disclaimer, I've written this extension.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is something to translate JSON Schema constraints into PostgreSQL ones, e.g.:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "age": {"minimum": 21}
    },
    "required": ["age"]
}
```

to:

```
SELECT FROM ...
WHERE (elem->>'age' >= 21)
```

I'm not aware of any existing tools.  I know of something similar for [MySQL](https://github.com/geraintluff/my-json) which might be useful for writing your own, but nothing for using the JSON type in PostgreSQL.

Comment: I thought that there isn't schema validation available at this point, do you know if there is a chance that we use V8 engine for validation e.g. in some OnUpdate/OnInsert actions ?

Comment: Oh! Sorry, I misunderstood and thought you were asking about using JSON Schema for queries, not validation.  Yeah, validating as a hook, or even validating in code before you submit seems reasonable.

Comment: check out this resource. might be helpful. http://blog.endpoint.com/2013/06/postgresql-as-nosql-with-data-validation.html